# In what cities are immigration checks by police common in the underground/subway/metro?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, public-transport, officials

For the first time in my life, I was stopped for an immigration check, which was on a metro platform in Sofia (Bulgaria). A police officer told me something in Bulgarian, and when I said (in Bulgarian) that I don't speak Bulgarian, his face changed and he said "bla bla bla pasport!" whereby I showed him my ID. As he spoke no English, he silently gave it back after 45 seconds.

In which cities is this common for this to happen in the underground? I've heard of it being the case in Tashkent (Uzbekistan)

Comment: What makes you think it was immigration check?  Rather than a simple document check.

Comment: @Karlson What's the difference? Isn't the purpose to establish whether the person is in Bulgaria legally? Besides, he only asked for it upon realising I was a foreigner

Comment: This is not Bulgaria specific and it's not limited to foreigners or to check the legality of presence.  Very similar practice happens in Russia.

Comment: @Karlson Right, and what I wonder is in what places this is common. Russia does not surprise me. In Tbilisi (Georgia) there was always one or two officers in the metro, but they only ever said "hello" to me at the most

Comment: Document check can happen in any country including the US: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop-and-frisk_in_New_York_City

Comment: While it's not common, it would be legal in any US transit system within 100 miles (ca. 160 km) of the external border for US Border Patrol to have a checkpoint or to stop someone "reasonably suspected" of being out of status. I'm not aware of this happening in any municipal rail systems, but there are YouTube videos showing it on intercity trains and buses near Canada.

Comment: @Karlson stop and frisk isn't a document check.

Comment: @phoog It's a document check with a bonus pat-down!

Comment: @MichaelHampton no. There is no obligation to identify yourself unless the police issue a summons or arrest you.  See http://www.nyclu.org/node/3249.

Comment: @phoog Give that a try and let us know what happens.

Comment: @MichaelHampton being a middle-aged, middle-class white guy, I would have great difficulty getting the police to stop me without actually doing something wrong (at which point they could compel me to identify myself).  But the NYPD themselves note that it is not a requirement to carry ID, though they recommend it (see http://www.nyc.gov/html/ccrb/downloads/pdf/Eng_PoliceEncounter.pdf: "Carry an ID at all times. While this is not a requirement, it’s good for your own safety to have one.") Given that, I imagine "what happens" if they find nothing in the search is that they let you go.

Comment: Here in the UK there's no obligation to carry any form of identification. See: http://law.stackexchange.com/a/594/1239

Comment: The defendant in the California case where requirement to carry ID was struck down was a member of the local chess club.

Comment: What is you aren't a member of a chess club?

Comment: @user19474 generally there's no requirement to carry ID in the US. Certain Allen's are required to carry proof of alien registration.

Comment: Oops!  "Certain Allen's" are "certain aliens"!